# Empty output scraping with cheerio

Tags: jquery, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I have been playing around and having fun with Node and CheerioJS for the last couple of days. I want to scrape this webpage, but for some reason I get an empty string back. Weird, because this exact method seems to work with other websites.

Here is what I have set up:

```js
const rp = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const bread = {
  uri: `https://www.ah.nl/producten/product/wi112339/ah-tijger-bruin-heel`,
  transform: function(body) {
    return cheerio.load(body);
  }
};

rp(bread).then(($) => {
  console.log($('.product__summary').text());
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

I want to get the product description:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKh0s.png) of [this](https://www.ah.nl/producten/product/wi112339/ah-tijger-bruin-heel) page, but I keep getting an empty string back. What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get to the answer, lets try checking the page in two different ways (on Chrome):

1.Right click -> view page source
2.Click F12

You will notice that the class "product__summary" exists only when we click F12, that is because only after the browser executes the page's scripts, elements with this class appear.

Cheerio does not execute scripts on the page, therefore you can't see this specific class.

You can use [Selenium](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver), which is pretty heavy to run on scale, or [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) which is lighter.

Good luck !

Comment: I see, makes sense of course. Thank you so much for your time! I'm going to try your suggestions!